# Props, TailwindCSS & Twin.Macro

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, tailwind-css, emotion

I am trying to get the following component to work properly with [Twin.Macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro):

```
import "twin.macro";

const Pattern = ({ classes }) => {
  return (
    <div css={[classes.wrapper]}>
      <img
        src="..."
        css={[classes.img]}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

In other words, I would like to receive the props via the `classes` prop and pass the values on to Twin.Macro.  However, it is not working properly.  For example, here is an implementation of that component:

```
<Pattern
  classes={{
    wrapper: "absolute -left-2 z-10 lg:left-0 top-0 h-full bg-contain bg-line-left-md lg:bg-line-left bg-no-repeat xl:bg-line-left-md hidden sm:block",
    img: "h-full",
  }}
/>
```

And here is the css that is output:

```
.css-w36jn9-Pattern {
    absolute -left-2 z-10 lg: left-0 top-0 h-full bg-contain bg-line-left-md lg:bg-line-left bg-no-repeat xl:bg-line-left-md hidden sm:block;
}
```

As you can see, all it does is pass on the values of the tailwind css classes.  It does not process those classes in the proper property-value pairs (such as position: absolute; left: -2px, etc).

I have tried different ways to get this to work, but nothing has been successful.  Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accordingly to [Twin.Macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro) when passing `css` property, you need to pass your classes to `tw` function using [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates). given you are passing a variable use also string interpolation.

finally, your code should look like:

```
import tw from "twin.macro";

const Pattern = ({ classes }) => {
  return (
    <div css={[tw`${classes.wrapper}`]}>
      <img
        src="..."
        css={[tw`${classes.img}`]}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have tried that also.  When I do that, I get the following message:  `TypeError: PATH__TO__FILE: twin.macro: Property value expected type of string but got null Learn more: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twin.macro
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)`.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have created a new question dealing with the problem mentioned in my previous answer.  If you are able, please feel free to take a look at it here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65700495/cannot-get-values-from-prop-in-twin-macro