# Cannot Get Values from Prop in Twin.macro

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, tailwind-css, emotion

You can see an example of what I am trying to do here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-leaf-qj8vz

Note:  this particular example is using [Twin.macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro) with Styled Components.  On my local computer I tried the same thing with the same results using Twin.macro with emotion/next.js.

Here is a sample component illustrating what I am trying to do:

```
import React from 'react'
import tw from 'twin.macro'

const Acme = ({ children, type }) => <div css={[tw`${type}`]}>{children}</div>

export default Acme
```

Here is how I would use that component:  `<Acme type="text-2xl">Text Goes Here</Acme>`

My expectation is that I will be able to style this instance of the `<Acme />` component via the tailwind css classes that I pass into the `type` prop.  Instead, I get the following error message:

```
/src/components/Acme.js: twin.macro: Property value expected type of string but got null Learn more: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twin.macro
```

When trying to figure this out, I noticed something interesting that may be relevant.  Here is a variation of the code that does work:

```
const Acme = ({ children, type }) => {
  const typeClass = 'text-2xl'
  const typeObj = {
    class: 'text-2xl',
  }

  return <div css={[tw`${typeClass}`]}>{children}</div>
}

export default Acme
```

Note that I have created a variable `typeClass` and set it to the same tailwind css class.  Note, in particular, the following line of code:

```
css={[tw`${typeClass}`]}
```

I have replace the prop `type` with the variable `typeClass`.  This works.  But now, instead of using the variable `typeClass` let's use the object `typeObj` that I have created as follows:

```
const Acme = ({ children, type }) => {
  const typeClass = 'text-2xl'
  const typeObj = {
    class: 'text-2xl',
  }

  return <div css={[tw`${typeObj.class}`]}>{children}</div>
}

export default Acme
```

This does **not** work and produces the same error:

```
/src/components/Acme.js: twin.macro: Property value expected type of string but got null Learn more: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twin.macro
```

This is so even though `typeClass === typeObj.class` evaluates to `true`.

I don't know if this is helpful, but perhaps it can help indicate a solution.  If I can get the `type` prop to behave like the `typeClass` variable then hopefully this would work.

Either way, any idea why this is not working and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: I see you find a way around, that's good! though I must say that error imo it's a bug from Twin.macro. this is a valid javascript syntax, and you are passing indeed a string as argument.

Comment: @buzatto The "owner" of Twin.macro explained why it does not work:  Twin is a babel-plugin and babel plugins don't execute the javascript you write, they let you traverse over it and customise things.  Babel doesn't have the ability to go searching for the variable you've defined within tw - it can do very basic executions but only when the variable it's looking for is plainly defined.  Here is the link where he wrote that:  https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro/issues/288#issuecomment-759751396

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer (meaning that someone else answered it on a different site).  Here is is.  I have to rewrite both the Component and the usage of the component as follows:

```
// Acme.js
const Acme = ({ children, type }) => <div css={[type]}>{children}</div>

---

// App.js
import tw from "twin.macro"

<Acme type={tw`text-2xl`}>Text Goes Here</Acme>
```

I have tried this out and it works.